# With statement for recordset field specification in Access 2003 VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, with-statement, ms-access-2003

I know of two ways to specify a field in a record set with VBA:

```
FooTable!BarField = 1
FooTable("Bar Field") = 2
```

But what happens in a With block?

```
With FooTable
    !BarField = 1
    ("Bar Field") = 2
End With
```

Is it possible to do both, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are all equivalent:

```
With FooTable
    .Fields("Bar Field").Value = 2  '.Value is default property of a Field object'
    .Fields("Bar Field") = 2  
    ![Bar Field] = 2
End With
```